# Is it possible to have automatic periodic file export of iCal calendars on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, mate, calendar, screenlets

Let's consider that we have

1. Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 LTS installed.
2. Google (or other) Calendar account.
3. Installed some application which can visualize the contents of iCal / iCalendar (ics-file) on desktop using widget / screenlet

   In this question I have installed ClearCalendar screenlet from `ppa:screenlets/ppa`. It has an option to show ics-file:

   > [image: ClearCalendar screenlet]

Which application(s) should I install or setup to get automatic periodic file export of iCal calendar on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular question and tools the following method looks reasonable.

1. Sign-in to Google Calendar account
2. Open *Settings*, go to *Settings for my calendars* and select needed calendar
3. Navigate to *Integrate calendar* subsection
4. Copy URL of iCal from *Secret address in iCal format* to clipboard (something like `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/yourusername%40gmail.com/private-01234567890abcdef0123456789abcde/basic.ics`)
5. Download `basic.ics` file as `~/calendar.ics` to test.
6. Write cron-job for our user for periodic downloading the iCal file.
7. Enjoy the calendar inside the ClearCalendar screenlet:

   [image: ClearCalendar with Calendar from iCal file]

---

Notes: ClearCalendar is very slow, shows event names and dates (without times) only after manual clicking on it and selecting *View Events* from context menu. So this solution is not good.